# Do friend functions add size to a C++ struct/class?

Tags: c++

What it looks like is happening is that memory is being used to store a function pointer inside every instance of my structs for every friend function declared inside of them. I had trouble finding info on this and needed confirmation before making major code changes.

The struct in question has about 10 million instances, so this becomes a significant amount of memory consumption.

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: Test it. Probably no. Friend stuff is a compile-time thing.

Comment: The answer is probably no, as `friend` doesn't actually add any code per-se, it just *allows* certain code to be compiled.

Comment: If you have a question about a specific piece of code then it would help to see that code. Show what you're doing that is changing the size of the struct.

Answer (score 4):

> Do friend functions add size to a C++ struct/class?

The language doesn't specify exhaustively what affect the size of a class. But in practice no, there is generally no reason why a friend function would need to affect the size of a class.

Answer (score 2):

The friend functions were not adding size to the struct.

If you must know the source of my stupidity so it is not repeated, I had an array of char pointers instead of an array of chars by mistake:

```
char* OwnerName[20];
```

instead of

```
char OwnerName[20];
```

Comment: Hehe, funny. That's one more reason to use `std::array`, `std::vector` and/or `std::string` you can't confuse them that easy ;)